# With React + TypeScript, how do I avoid typecasting when using optional props with defaults with strictNullChecks enabled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

If I have the following component

```
interface Props {
    someOptionalProp?: string;
}


class SomeComponent extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    public static defaultProps = {
        someOptionalProp: 'some default'
    };

    public render() {
        this.props.someOptionalProp.indexOf('a'); // Type error

        return <div />;
    }
}
```

Then `this.props.someOptionalProp` has type `string | undefined`, since this is an optional field of the `Props` interface. However, at runtime it cannot be undefined since defaultProps are set for this prop.

Is there any way to avoid typecasting in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) for this purpose:

```
this.props.someOptionalProp!.indexOf('a')
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript is trying to warn you that probably this props will have no value. 
Anyways, if you want to be specific in the type used, you can use Type Assertion.

Note that **type assertions** are purely a **compile time** construct and a way for you to provide hints to the compiler on how you want your code to be analyzed.

You could read more here: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

In your case the solution could be:

```
(this.props.someOptionalProp as string).indexOf('a');
```